# Eclipse doesn't find libnppc.so.7.0 library to run a python code, containing Opencv commands which use CUDA libraries

Tags: python, c++, eclipse, opencv, cuda

I have OPENCV 2.4.10 and CUDA 7.5 installed on Ubuntu 14.4 LTS.

By running a simple python code which uses opencv libraries through terminal,it works well without any problem, but when I make a Pydev Project in eclipse and make a new source python file and paste the above code in it, after running it in eclipse gives the following error.

```
ImportError: libnppc.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

this is the paths in .bashrc file:

```
# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

export PATH="/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/username/anaconda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

in eclipse the following path is for Python Interpreter:

```
/home/username/anaconda/bin
```

libraries in Cuda-7.0:

```
 $/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib64$ ls
 cudnn.h              libcuinj64.so     libcublas_device.a 
 libcuinj64.so.7.0    libcublas.so      libnppi_static.a
 libcublas.so.7.0     libcuinj64.so.7.0.18   libnpps.so
 libculibos.a         libnpps.so.7.0    libcublas.so.7.0.18 
 libcurand.so         libcublas_static.a  libcurand.so.7.0 
 libnpps.so.7.0.18    libcudadevrt.a      libnpps_static.a
 libcudart.so         libcurand.so.7.0.18 libnvblas.so
 libcudart.so.7.0     libcurand_static.a  libnvblas.so.7.0
 libcusolver.so       libcudart.so.7.0.18 libcusolver.so.7.0     
 libnvblas.so.7.0.18  libcudart_static.a  libnvrtc-builtins.so
 libcudnn.so          libcusolver.so.7.0.18  libnvrtc-builtins.so.7.0
 libcudnn.so.6.5      libcusolver_static.a   
 libcudnn.so.6.5.48   libcusparse.so         libnvrtc-builtins.so.7.0.18
 libcudnn_static.a    libcusparse.so.7.0     libnvrtc.so
 libcufft.so          libnvrtc.so.7.0
 libcufft.so.7.0      libcusparse.so.7.0.18  
 libcusparse_static.a libnvrtc.so.7.0.17
 libcufft.so.7.0.18   libnppc.so             libnvToolsExt.so
 libcufft_static.a    libnppc.so.7.0         libnvToolsExt.so.1
 libcufftw.so         libnvToolsExt.so.1.0.0
 libcufftw.so.7.0     libnppc.so.7.0.18      libOpenCL.so
 libnppc_static.a     libOpenCL.so.1
 libcufftw.so.7.0.18  libnppi.so           
 libcufftw_static.a   libnppi.so.7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

Eclipse is looking for cuda folder not cuda-7.0 folder, so I had do build symbolink links of the libraries in cuda-7.0 in cuda folder as well.

this solved the problem.